# How do we change the channel datatype in spring integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, channel

Assume like below code as my implementation

```
<int:channel id="channel"/>
    <int:inbound-channel-adapter id="inAdapter" channel="channel" method="produce">
        <bean class="spring.integration.stackoverflow.ioadapter.Application$MessageProducer"/>
        <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
    </int:inbound-channel-adapter>
    <int:outbound-channel-adapter id="outAdapter" channel="channel" method="consume">
        <bean class="spring.integration.stackoverflow.ioadapter.Application$MessageConsumer"/>
    </int:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Here default datatype as "String". How do we change the data type for java.util.List? Which means i need to produce list of objects & consume the same.

Comment: There is no such a String default in Spring. I somehow think you refer to your own code, but didn’t elaborate. Please, consider to share more info

Comment: Yup..Solved the issue @ArtemBilan

Comment: Ok. So, time to share your experience in the answer or just delete the question from SO altogether!